# How can I change the coordinate of part of an object to change the coordinate of all objects?

Tags: transforms, coordinates, marker

Imagine I have an object which is a vertebra with some markers on it. When I go to the edit mode and select each marker, I can easily see their coordinate of them. Now, if I want to register new coordinations to my markers to move them to a new place by changing their XYZ, only markers move, and the main object doesn't move.
How can I lock my main model to the markers to transform it into a new place by changing the coordination of markers?
I appreciate any help you can provide.
[image: This is the first image; the spheres are the markers in the first position]
[image: I selected one of the markers as an example, and I can see its coordinates.]
[image: But here, when I put the new coordination for my marker, the main object doesn't move with the marker.]

Comment: Why can’t you just transform the object has a whole to where you want it? Are you looking for deforming the vertebrae, or simply rotating it so that the three points closest to the spheres stay close to them?

Comment: Thanks, @TheLabCat; no, I would like to simulate the motion; it means that the vertebra should go to the new place by changing the coordination of the markers. Still, when I change the marker's location, as you can see, the vertebra stays in the last place and doesn't move while the markers have moved.

Comment: That still doesn’t appear to mean you can’t just transform the object as a whole, or use an armature deform. The markers are part of the same mesh, so they can *never* transform the rest of the mesh as is. They’d have to be separate objects.

Comment: What simulation system are you using?